# Is this initialisation of a primitive variable correct?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm calling something like this kind of function here I have a variable named **index** I'm initiating it to 0 initially because I have a static analyzer leak in that initialization line. Is this the correct way of resolving that leak? Since I'm initiating to 0 and after my first `if` condition becomes true then again assigning to 0. Would this cause any problems?

```
 -(NSString *)loadSelected:(NSString*)selectedOptn{
        int index = 0;
        if ([selectedOptn isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
            index = 0;
        }
        else if([selectedOptn isEqualToString:@"B"]){
            index = 1;
        }
        else if([selectedOptn isEqualToString:@"C"]){
            index = 2;
        }
        else if([selectedOptn isEqualToString:@"D"]){
            index = 3;
        }
        return [[array.options objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"xyz"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't cause any problems, I'm curious to know what the error was though - are you sure it wasn't just warning you that you hadn't initialised it or something?

Comment: @user1095157 what warning was it? warning are bad